# Remove lines around contourf with matplotlib and cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I Have this map, made with cartopy like this:
`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})
fig.set_size_inches(15, 10, forward=True)
ax.set_extent([-75.5,-30,-31,6.5])

grid=ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,linewidth=0.05, color='gray', alpha=0.5)
grid.top_labels = False
grid.right_labels = False
grid.xlabel_style = {'color': 'grey', 'weight': 'bold', 'size': 'small'}
grid.ylabel_style = {'color': 'grey', 'weight': 'bold', 'size': 'small'}
ax.axis('off')
               
precip_colormap = colors.ListedColormap(nws_precip_colors)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(levels, val)

data_crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()
cs = ax.contourf(lonsi, latsi, values, transform=data_crs, levels=levels, cmap=precip_colormap, add_colorbar=False, extend='both', alpha=0.8, norm=norm, edgecolor=None)

plt.title(titulo_mapa, fontsize=20, pad=30, fontweight='bold', color='grey', fontproperties=prop)
cbar=plt.colorbar(cs)
cbar.set_ticks(levels)
cbytick_obj = plt.getp(cbar.ax.axes, 'yticklabels')                
plt.setp(cbytick_obj, color='grey')
```

and it's fine, but I want to remove this border around the colors, like this where i circled.

[image: map]

I didn't find any solution anywhere :(

Comment: What do you get if you change the colormap to `cmap="Reds"`?

Comment: the problem is the alpha - you have overlapping polygons which doesn't work well with transparency. there's not really a good way around this, except that if you're just looking for a more pastel color palette you can specify a different `cmap` but drop the `alpha=0.8`

Comment: remove the `alpha` worked! thank you